# DirectLine client receives multiple response from bot on websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm developing a chat bot using swagger and directline on Node.js following [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLineWebSockets):
(https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLineWebSockets)

Each time I send a message to the bot I receive multiple respone for each messages sent before.

Example:

*message sent 1*

response 1

*message sent 2*

response 2

response 2

*message sent 3*

response 3

response 3

response 3

The use case is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742731/directlinejs-receiving-copies-of-bot-replies), but with websocket.

([DirectLineJS receiving copies of Bot replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742731/directlinejs-receiving-copies-of-bot-replies))

send message:

```
// send message to bot
  function sendMessages(client, conversationId, utterance) {

        logger.debug("*** SEND A MESSAGE ");

        client.Conversations.Conversations_PostActivity(
                    {
                          conversationId: conversationId,
                          activity: {
                               textFormat: config.activity.textFrormat,
                               text: utterance,
                               type: config.activity.type,
                               from: {
                                     id: callSid
                               }
                          }
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                          logger.error('Error sending message:', err.statusText);
                          callback(null,err);
                    });
  }
```

receives activity:

```
  function startReceivingWebSocketClient(streamUrl, conversationId) {

        logger.debug('Starting WebSocket Client for message streaming on conversationId: ' + conversationId+ ' , watermark: '+waterMark);

      var ws = new (webSocket.client)();

      ws.on('connectFailed', function (error) {
        logger.debug('Connect Error: ' + error.toString() );
      });

      ws.on('close', function(){
        logger.debug('Connect Close: ' + error.toString());
      });

      ws.on('connect', function (connection) {

        logger.debug('WebSocket Client Connected');
          connection.on('error', function (error) {
              logger.debug("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
          });
          connection.on('close', function () {
              logger.debug('WebSocket Client Disconnected');
          });
          connection.on('message', function (message) {
              // Occasionally, the Direct Line service sends an empty message as a liveness ping
              // Ignore these messages
              if (message.type === 'utf8' && message.utf8Data.length > 0) {

                  var responseMessage = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);

                  if(responseMessage.watermark > waterMark)
                  {
                    logger.debug("responseMessage.watermark > waterMark     "+responseMessage.watermark +">"+ waterMark);
                     var activities = responseMessage.activities;
                     activities = activities.filter(function (m) { return m.from.id == config.directLine.from.id });
                     activities = activities.filter(function (m) { return m.conversation.id == conversationId });
                     if(activities.length>0)
                     {
                           waterMark = responseMessage.watermark;
                           logger.debug("************** attività: "+JSON.stringify(responseMessage));
                           sendResponse(activities);
                     }

                  }
              }
          });
      });

      ws.connect(streamUrl);

  }
```

Comment: Is the problem happening if you run the sample?

Comment: The sample works correctly but here is a substantial difference: the sample open a single websocket and manages all messages on this.

My solution is an http stateless application and connects a new websocket each message sent through a get http request.
I think that  should be closed or released the connection on websocket, HOW?

Comment: @CarloStefani Based on your comment, it seems you should be using Polling instead of web sockets.  In the Bot Builder, a client that uses Web Sockets will receive messages on the socket.  Closing and re-opening the connection defeats the purpose.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your suggestion and i think the same. I'm testing websocket solution because the old implementation with polling was too slow. The polling interval must be setted minimum at 800ms to get the response at first poll, is too much.